# "is believed to still be" or "is believed to be still"

Tags: verbs, adverbs, word-order

I wonder which of the following is correct.

> It is believed to still be efficiently solvable.

and

> It is believed to be still efficiently solvable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Position of adverbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/432289/position-of-adverbs) Specifically, one of the answers there sdays [2.the adverb "still" is placed before the action verb but after the be verb .in negative sentences,still comes before the auxiliary.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/432366/2637)

Comment: Out of those two choices I would favor Door #3: "It is still believed to be efficiently solvable."

Comment: @Robusto: I would argue that your construction subtly changes the meaning: __It is still believed to be efficiently solvable__ implies that there are those who believe it was _never_ efficiently solvable, while OP's 2 versions implies that everyone believes that, at some point, it _was_ efficiently solvable (even if it is no longer).

Comment: @Zack: I take your point. If the intended meaning is that the solvability window is in danger of closing, then my Door #3 doesn't work. But that is only true in that one instance. In the more likely case that *still* governs the belief, Door #3 works better.

Comment: @Robusto: Fair enough. And I think your construction certainly _sounds_ better. :)

Answer (score 1):

I disagee with @RogerK - sentence #1 is best:

> It is believed to still be efficiently solvable.

First, it's 100% correct. No problem there. Second, it avoids the "be still" combo in the other sentence. And that's a little weird sounding, to be honest. All those b's one after another, and the expression "be still" is a thing too, so the reader needs to unconsciously disambiguate.

Regardless, I'd do whatever I could to substitute that passive voice "It is believed..." for active voice: *Who* believes this? In a weak research paper, passive voice is often used to cover up a lack of research...