# "I have possibly the same [thing]" or "I possibly have the same [thing]"

Tags: word-order, adverb-position

Do you say:

1. I have possibly the same [thing]
2. I possibly have the same [thing]

Also:

1. I may have possibly [done something]
2. I may possibly have [done something]

Google search returns almost equal amount of results for both variants

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Position of adverbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/432289/position-of-adverbs)

Comment: number 1 means I have something and it might be the same thing.  Number 2 means I might have the same thing.  In 2 you may or may not have anything. In 1 you definitely have something but whether it’s the same is a question.  In other words the possibility attaches to ’same’ in 1, but ‘have’ in 2.

Comment: @Jim thank you! That answers my question!